# Combing base data set for a formula from two *other* Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We have hit the dreaded 5 million rows limit which is so small for any semi-serious data.

We have an important `ArrayFormula` piece in one of our worksheets (tab) currently that summarizes the data from another worksheet in the same file where time series data is kept with dates. This is our current function:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(DataSheet!$B:$B, 
          MONTH(DataSheet!$A:$A), 1, 
          YEAR(DataSheet!$A:$A), 2020)
)
```

Explanation: This basically summed all of column B in the `DataSheet` tab for the month of Jan 2020 based on date found in column A of that sheet.

However, this worksheet of data that is now running close to that row limit. We can move it to another Google Sheets file, and refer to the same data via `IMPORTRANGE`.

The question then is how to refer to that data instead of the `DataSheet!$A:$A` in the above old formula? Will this reference be replaced by the entire IMPORTRANGE function?

Old:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(DataSheet!$B:$B, 
          MONTH(DataSheet!$A:$A), 1, 
          YEAR(DataSheet!$A:$A), 2020)
)
```

New:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(IMPORTRANGE(filename, rows)!$B:$B, 
          MONTH(IMPORTRANGE(filename, rows)!$A:$A, 1, 
          YEAR(IMPORTRANGE(filename, rows)!$A:$A, 2020)
)
```

This does *not* work of course, because we cannot have the exclamation `!` followed by the column in an `importrange`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but i don't know that you've provided enough info about your setup to help you with the specifics of that reference.  Also, there is no 500K limit that I am aware of.  Check out IMPORTRANGE()

Comment: This is the issue we see: imgur.com/a/lxoA1d3 -- 5 million rows limit. Thanks for importrange(). I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: `We can move it to another Google Sheets file, and refer to the same data via IMPORTRANGE` I'm not sure I understand this. Do you want to move the data to another sheet? Wouldn't you have the same problem (5 million limit)? Or you want to move only part of it? Could you please provide more details about your issue?

Comment: Yes, moving it will keep us under the limit. Right now, we have a few tabs (worksheets) within the same file and the many `ArrayFormula` functions which I suppose are counted towards the 5 million count. Anyway, the question is: how do I refer to an IMPORTRANGE inside an ArrayFormula.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cell A1 on a fresh, brand new tab somewhere:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(1*TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("[spreadsheet key]","Sheet1!A:B"),{"mmmyyyy","0.00"}),"select Col1,SUM(Col2) where Col2<>0 group by Col1 order by Col1")
```

The "spreadsheet key" is the combination of letters and numbers after the "/d/" and before the "/edit..." in the URL of your source sheet.
Obviously, you'd also replace "Sheet1!A:B" with whatever the real tab/column reference is.

Then, select all of Column A and from the Menu choose Format>Number>More Formats>Custom Number Formatting, Then this in the dialog box:

mmmm yyyy

Comment: I need a specific month and year number, not to list all of them. I suppose I could do that with an additional WHERE clause. Anyway, this above formula gives this error: `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC`. I suppose that's because the column in which numbers to be summed are kept are not in the second col, `Col2`. Can I change that to `Col8` as it's column H in the sheet? THat doesn't work either.

Comment: @PKHunter It's really tough to do all of this blind.  If you share a sample sheet with some data that looks like your real data, i can build a the right formula for you there, using an IMPORTRANGE() to pretend that I'm calling a different sheet altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the offer to create something @MattKing - I cannot share the files for now, and creating demos I'm not sure is worth the effort. The question is: how should I replace `OldSheet!A:A` with an `ImportRange` equivalent...referring to a specific column in the imported file.

Comment: @PKHunter =IMPORTRANGE("url of other spreadhseet","OldSheet!A:A")

Comment: Matt - here's the data file: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18pEipS14cz6lZO6q3rwBW2Vwm2OaDBUFIigQX25PYO4/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to bring two tabs from that file above into one table in this file...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tnTt1U8pn9G-zMySHv8K806EQhUGGLoklTTTaPHxlBk/edit?usp=sharing

You can see the formula in A1 in this second file. But it is NOT bringing the collective rows from the two tabs, just the data from the first tab.

Comment: yes the small file is working. The larger file has some error and Google's errors in this context are hideously uninformative. I've dropped this whole idea and taken up a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You want to `IMPORTRANGE` from two different sheets in a different spreadsheet.

While the following formula will import data from both sheets, it will also import the blank rows, so you might have to scroll down hundreds of rows in order to see the data from the second sheet (and this might give your the wrong impression that the second sheet is not getting imported):

```
{
  IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_ID","CurrentMonth!$A:$J");
  IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_ID","All2020!$A:$J")
}
```

You can use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) in order to filter out blank rows:

```
=QUERY(
  {
   IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_ID","CurrentMonth!$A:$J");
   IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_ID","All2020!$A:$J")
  },
  "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col1 DESC"
)
```

[image]

#### Note:

- I thought you'd like to sort the data according to the date in column A, please remove `ORDER BY Col1 DESC` if that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you, but is QUERY really needed for this? Wouldn't just the parantheses work?

Comment: @PKHunter `QUERY` is used here to get rid of the blank rows in the original sheets. Data from both sheets is getting imported when using `{ IMPORTRANGE(); IMPORTRANGE() }`, but you are not seeing the data from the second sheet because there are hundreds of blank rows in between (take a look at row 1001).

Comment: @PKHunter I edited my answer in order to explain this.

Comment: Thank you, this is very thorough and works. But putting it in my real use case gives a cryptic "REF!" error. No explanation of what's wrong. The data in the two sheets I am trying to combine is correct, and their names in my formula are correct. Any pointers?

Comment: @PKHunter Could you provide a copy of the spreadsheet with sample data that shows this behaviour?